# Application keystore not found for signing config 'externalOverride'

Tags: java, android, gradle

So I switched from Ubuntu where I developed and released 3 versions of my app (updates) to Windows where I copied keystore for signed apps and now when I'm trying to release a new version it's giving me the error

```
Application keystore not found for signing config 'externalOverride'
```

At first I got `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect` error but I solved it with changing keystore password with CMD.

Now I'm getting this and can't find solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when the IDE is not able to locate the jks file. Go to the explorer and find look for the jks file